# Adding new key-value pair in array overwrites the last one

Tags: php, arrays

I am making an ecommerce site. I want to store the product_id of the product which the user adds to the cart (i.e. the product_id is the key and quantity is the value) into an array.

```
$product_id = 'first';
//$product_id = 'second';

    $add[$product_id] = 1;
    //$add[$product_id] = 2;

    print_r($add);
```

This code prints out: `Array ( [first] => 1 )`

When i change the value of $product_id to 'second' and value to '2' like:

```
//$product_id = 'first';
$product_id = 'second';

    //$add[$product_id] = 1;
    $add[$product_id] = 2;

  print_r($add);
```

The output is: `Array ( [second] => 2 )`

The second insert overwrites the first key-value pair.

NOTE- I cannot use the foreach() or any other loop because the value is inserted only when the page is loaded (i.e. once per page).

How can i prevent the second value to override the previous one and add them incrementally (without any loop)

Comment: If the page refresh every time you add a product to the cart the $add array will reset every time. Try and store the cart info on client side using cookies or localStorage if available. Then at checkout send the info to php.

Comment: Thanks @Allkin . I definitely will try that out.